# gunicorn critical time-out: settings seem to get ignored

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I keep running into 502 bad gateway error while trying to upload files from my django app. 
Nginx error log points me to gunicorn. I have set up asyncronous workers to deal with the problem but it does not work. I keep getting the error when uploading slightly big files.

Here is my gunicorn error log:

```
[2020-05-18 22:49:47 +0000] [2867] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2020-05-18 22:49:47 +0000] [2870] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2870
[2020-05-18 22:49:47 +0000] [2879] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2879
[2020-05-18 22:49:47 +0000] [2891] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2891
[2020-05-18 22:49:47 +0000] [2892] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2892
[2020-05-18 22:49:47 +0000] [2894] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2894
[2020-05-18 22:58:28 +0000] [2867] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2892)
[2020-05-18 22:59:48 +0000] [2925] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2925
[2020-05-18 23:10:14 +0000] [2867] [INFO] Handling signal: term
```

and here is what my gunicorn config look like:
gunicorn/config.py

```
BASE_DIR = "/home/ubuntu/"
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)


bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
backlog = 2048

import multiprocessing
workers = 5
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 300
graceful_timeout = 300
keepalive = 300
```

and then gunicorn.conf

```
[program:gunicorn]

directory=/home/ubuntu/mysite
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn  --config /home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/mysite/app.sock app.wsgi:application

autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log


[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue there, am I ommitting something to prevent time out there.

UPDATE: I have seen places that gunicorn is binded to the localhost rather than the socket. Maybe that could be the solution but I don't understand why

Comment: I guess the timeout value is not big enough as the error message indicates. Can you increase timeout value in your config file?

Comment: I can, but it times out much before the time out limit, would that be a gunicorn related problem?

Comment: Note that nginx itself has a default timeout of 60 seconds but when you hit that limit it should respond with HTTP 504 (see [proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)).

Comment: yes I have set that one out too! I am so confused literally its been like a week on that 502 error and I am still in the dark about the why

Comment: It can be anything, but we need to change things step by step to understand which is the root cause. Try to increase gunicorn and nginx timeout one by öne and see it changes. By the way, can you trace the time that how long it takes to return a 502 response? Once, I have faced with a loadbalancer timeout which is default to 60 seconds

Comment: I see I am on it! So the error seems to be somewhat unrelated to time because I have had a 2mo file taking 40 s + 30 s processing working fine and a 3 mo file taking 30 secondes to downlaod and giving a 502 bad gateway error within a few seconds